Ubuntu 23.10 Only Booting to Network Image
I have an HP 2570p laptop that has been running Ubuntu 23.10 successfully until I tried updating to 24.04.
Having updated, on every boot the laptop tries to load a network image instead of booting to the HDD. I have reinstalled various versions of Ubuntu with the same results. Irritatingly a clean install of Windows 10 shuts down and boots correctly.
I have also tried the many suggestions using BootRepair, again with no success.
Be aware that I cannot access the BIOS settings as the laptop has a BIOS password although the BIOS settings did not stop Ubuntu booting and running previously.
Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks in advance.
EDIT To clarify, the laptop is attempting a PXE boot which fails. The re-installation of various Ubuntu versions (22.10, 23.10, 24.04) returned no errors. Installation was done with a bootable USB created with Rufus. Tried UEFI and BIOS installs all with the same result.

Updated original post with more detail, as requested.

As you can boot from one, when you're performing the installation, try inserting another flash drive and setting it as the bootloader target instead of the main disk
I suspect a BIOS setting may be the culprit, though the more business-oriented HP models are designed to prevent a trivial reset (jumper, remove internal battery, etc.) .. HP support might help you out as it's an older model or a local computer store may be hack it

Given that a new BIOS chip or a BIOS password reset were not worth the time and money, I decided to cut my losses and move from my HP laptop to a reconditioned tower PC!
